# Auto populate dropDownListRow form field in yii from database

Tags: php, yii, multi-select, dropdownlistfor

I have a form having some multi select dropdowns in yii. I have to auto populate the selected values in that multi select box when comes to edit the data. I am fetching the data and passing it inot view file, but am not sure how can i populate the values in the dropdown. please help me

Here is the code for the multi select drop down

```
echo $form->dropDownListRow($modelDomain, 'domain_id',  $domain, array('title' => Yii::t('main', 'SELECT_DOAMIN'),'multiple'=>true ,'style' => 'width:250px;height:150px;'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For multiple select you need to use 'options' parameter:

```
echo $form->dropDownListRow($modelDomain, 'domain_id',  $domain, array('title' => Yii::t('main', 'SELECT_DOAMIN'),'multiple'=>true ,'style' => 'width:250px;height:150px;', 'options' => array(
1 => array('selected' => 'selected'),
2 => array('selected' => 'selected'),
)));
```

Where 1 and 2 are domain ids taken from the $_POST;

You can do this in the action:

```
$post = $this->getRequest()->getPost('ModelName');
$selectedDomains = $post['domain_id']; // this should be an array or selected values
$selected = array_fill(0, count($selectedDomains), array('selected' => 'selected')); // this constructs the 'options' value from view
$selectedOptions = array_combine($selectedDomains, $selected) // this is the 'options' array with selected values as keys and htmlOptions as values
```

Also, the code is untested and you need to do your validations and other logic stuff yourself.